# Facebook keeps sending messages at Enter key instead of making a new line

Tags: facebook, comments

When I am replying to a message in Facebook and I press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key it sends the message instead of moving to the next line.

How do I add extra lines in my comments before I actually post the message?

Answer (score 5):

If you have the enter arrow box unchecked as shown in the figure below you will be able to go to next line by pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Otherwise it will send your message![image]

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why Facebook is behaving this way, but you could try pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. This should also enter a new line without shifting focus.

Answer (score 1):

ctrl + enter creates a line break, everything after the cursor moves down to a new line